# How to check `not between` date

Tags: mysql

I'm writing the education foundation system.
It has donators, students, enrollments, university and scholar transactions.

I have the following query which `mainly` lists the university list together with students count.

What I need is those students must NOT be between specified date as you can see in following query.

The query I need is `...AND t.taken_out_at NOT BETWEEN those dates...`. I need to get transactions not between those dates.

How can I get it?

```
SELECT 
u.*, 
r.name as region, 
count(e.student_id) AS student_count 
FROM universities u 
    JOIN regions r ON u.region_id = r.region_id 
    JOIN enrollments e ON e.university_id = u.university_id 
    JOIN transactions t ON t.student_id = e.student_id 
WHERE u.region_id = r.region_id
AND t.taken_out_at between 2021-12-01 AND 2021-12-31
GROUP BY university_id;
```

The table structure is :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `AND t.taken_out_at NOT between 2021-12-01 AND 2021-12-31`? This [should work](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-between)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You could do `AND (t.taken_out_at < 2021-12-01 OR t.taken_out_at > 2021-12-31)`

Answer (score 0):

simply like this:

```
[...]
WHERE u.region_id = r.region_id
AND t.taken_out_at NOT BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
[...]
```

(note also the quotes around the dates)